# Seach-and-Replace with Groups in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to capture groups and store them for usage in the replace field of VS Code?

For example, I would like to replace all import statement paths to use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
import Something from "../../Something.tsx"
```

Replace with

```
import Something from '../../Something.tsx'
```

I would have to capture the path and use it later.

Comment: create groups and reference them with `$1`, `$2`, ...., read about JavaScript Regular Expressions

Comment: Is this a find/replace within one files or search/replace across multiple files?

Comment: @Mark Across multiple files. I'd like to replace everything that comes up in the search tab.

Comment: The Search and Replace view  can do regex searches - there is a regex option button to the right `.*` to enable.  And then any capture groups in your find regex can be used in the replace field as `$1`, `$2`, etc.  You should really try to work out the regex yourself first.

Comment: Yeah thanks both of you for finding me the answer!